# OpenLayers3: How to use zIndex for Layers

Tags: openlayers

In my project I have the following situation:

```
layer A: zIndex = 1000;
layer B: zIndex = 2000;
layer C: zIndex = 3000;
layer D: zIndex = 4000;
```

I add the layers in this order:

```
layer A, layer C, layer D, layer B
```

I expect that correspondent to the zIndex the layers are in the following order:

```
layer A, layer B, layer C, layer D
```

But they are not! I get the order as they are added.

My questions:

- Is the zIndex mechanism implemented - I'm using OL3.15.x and OL3.16.0?
- How to set the zIndex to get the wanted result?
- Are there any limitations on zIndex?
- Should I add the layer before setting the zIndex?

Currently I'm porting a huge project from OpenLayers2 to Openlayers3. In OL2 this worked and with OL3 not.

This is a code snipped for one layer. The other layers are created in a similar way:

```
var sourceA = new ol.source.Vector({
 loader: fetchData,
 strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
});
if (sourceA) {
 var layerA = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: sourceA,
  visible: false
 });
 if (layerA) {
  layerA.setZIndex(ZINDEX_LAYER_A);
  ...
  map.addLayer(layerA);
  ...
 }
}
```

Comment: The Z indexing works just fine, take a look at this example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.16.0/examples/layer-z-index.html
could you provide some code of yours? It's hard to figure out what's wrong without any actual code

Comment: Please ask only one question per question as per the [Tour].